# Why does this element does not respect specificity rules?

Tags: css, firefox

So I was tweaking the Firefox built-in reader mode using Stylish extension. The first thing I did was to change the font:

```css
body.loaded.serif div#moz-reader-content, h1#reader-title, div#reader-credits{
  font-family: "Marion";
}
```

It worked fine. Later on I wanted to tweak the links:

```css
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

And the links stay unchanged. I can see in Firebug that this declaration is overriden by the default style declaration (as in "aboutReaderContent.css") which also used a single selector. Then I tried making it more specific:

```css
html body.serif.loaded div.content div#moz-reader-content p a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Still no effect. Firebug says it was still overriden. I had to resort to `!important`.

My question is, why did this element does not follow the specificity rule? As I understand it, even in multiple files, browser will follow the most "specific" selector regardless the order these files are loaded. To add to my confusion, the first tweak actually overrode the default stylesheet, but that's in another file "aboutReader.css". What am I missing?

Comment: Are you able to provide us some live code ?

Comment: you mean to say with this selector `html body.serif.loaded div.content div#moz-reader-content p a{}` also you couldn't change the property ?

Comment: @MohammedMoustafa what do you mean by live code?

Comment: @K.C. Yes. Firefox does not recognize this until I specify `!important`.

Comment: Demo code on jsffidle or here.

Comment: @MohammedMoustafa I've provided all code I used in the question. What else demo do you need?

Comment: I want to see how it behaves

Comment: @MohammedMoustafa Desired behavior: the code `html body.serif.loaded div.content div#moz-reader-content p a{text-decoration:none;}` should work. Actual behavior: it doesn't. Firebug says it's overriden by default style declaration `a{text-decoration:underline;}` in aboutReaderContent.css.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think any one can figure out what the answer is!!! we need the related html part and css both together or something similar to your code. (We can know you have nesting your code from css but we don't know if your (html)'s order or nesting is right or something is missing). How we going to know something is missing from most are missing!!! and it could be nesting problem.